# issue with getting position of an element

Tags: javascript

im having issue with getting position of an element. there are 4divs with position relative. but and float is left. when im trying to get the left position on an element it returns null. in jquery it returns 0. can some one help me please.

Thanks,
Dakshina.

Comment: Yeah, you need to show some code

Comment: //parent item
div.contblock{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:440px;
 padding-top:10px;
 position:relative;
}
//child item
div.mrblcks{
 width:215px;
 height:100px;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 padding-right:5px;
 position:relative;
}



     <div class="contblock">
      <div class="mrblcks" onmouseover="alert(this.style.left);">       
       <h3>Adithya Resort</h3>
       <p>
       <img src="images/up_images/hotels/thumbnails/043321_adithya.jpg" alt="Adithya resort" />
       Aditya Beach Resort with
<a href="#" title="Adithya Resort Gall">read more</a>
       </p>
      </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
var el = document.getElementById(<id>);
var left=0, top=0;
do {
  left += el.offsetLeft;
  top += el.offsetTop;
}while(el = el.offsetParent);
```

// 'left' and 'top' will give you the x,y position.

Comment: hi,
this works fine. but is there any way to use this with jquery.
thanks for the help.

Comment: element.offset() should give you the answer. Take a look at
http://api.jquery.com/offset/